# Media queries for video size not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, html5-video

I have a video in my html and the width is set to 75% in the css and I want to set it to 100% on the media query for mobile devices. However when I try to change the width to 100% in the media query...nothing happens. Here is a picture of how it looks now: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AR5R8.png)

I tried setting the width to 100% (not in a media query) and when I resize it down it looks the way I want it on mobile devices but then it's also 100% width on desktop size and I don't want that.

So in summary, I want it to stay 75% width on desktop size and anything for example... below 600px to be 100% width.

Here is my html: `

```
 <section id="game-video">

        <div class="video-container">
            <video src="videos/video.mp4"
            controls></video>
        </div>


    </section>
```

`

Here is my css: `

```
.video-container video
 {
    display: block; 
    width: 75%; 
    margin: 0 auto;  
}
```

`

Media query: `

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .video-container video {
    
    width: 100%; 
     
  }
}
```

`

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) preferably in a [Stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), there are no media queries in your example.

Answer (score 1):

If you have set up your media query like this, it should work.

Otherwise you have something that is overriding it.

```css
#game-video, .video-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.video-container video {
  display: block;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .video-container video {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="game-video">
  <div class="video-container">
    <video src="videos/video.mp4" controls></video>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I have exactly the same media query and it still doesn't work

Comment: Please read the text about how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in a [Stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) and update your question. You need to provide enough information to help you.

Comment: The <video> tag has a default object-fit: contain; value.  Try playing with that.